# Algorithm which creates all possible Latin squares

Tags: algorithm, latin-square

I need help with algorithm, which creates all Latin squares up to n=10. I am in the point, when i have created n! Latin squares and I have tried to permute rows and columns afterwards, so it gave me n!*n!*n! Latin squares, but according to wikipedia(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square) this extension of n! Latin squares is wrong. Don't have anyone any idea how to get all possible Latin Squares?

Answer (score 3):

Your effort is, alas, doomed. We still don't know a formula for calculating the number of Latin squares of size `n`. However, someone poor soul did work it out for `n=10`. Whilst generating the squares is possible (you can always just generate all possibilities, and see if they're a latin square), you're going to get

```
9,982,437,658,213,039,871,725,064,756,920,320,000
```

answers ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square)).

So, I hope you've got a big hard disk and a lot of time.

Comment: I formulated my question little bit wrong.We are trying to write an algorithm which can create as many Latin squares as it can. Latin square has side n=1,2,...10. To n=6 the number is not so high(according to sheet on wikipedia)

Comment: @prone666 : What do you mean by 'as many Latin square as it can' - in some fixed time? You might also see this : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145228/formula-for-the-number-of-latin-squares-of-size-n

Comment: Better check this one too http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63131/generate-random-latin-squares